# Can variables be treated as constants in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

This is an embarrassingly basic question, but until recently I have avoided properly understanding IO in Haskell and now I need to.

I am writing (with someone else) a program that takes as part of its input a library of background data. So as part of `main` I'll have a couple of lines such as

```
lib <- library.txt
let library = interpret lib
```

That is, it reads the library from a text file and then parses it to create a library with the right structure needed for the program. In particular, the type of "interpret" will be

```
interpret :: String -> Library
```

My question now is this. Is there some way for the program to treat the library as a constant? The program will contain functions whose behaviour depends on what's in the library, so it seems as though one would have to give such a function a type such as

```
foo :: Library -> Type1 -> Type2
```

and always include `library` as one of the arguments of `foo`. But that is a bit tedious when `foo` will only ever be applied to `library` and not some other library of type `Library`. I'd like to be able to treat `library` as I would a constant such as 2 (the analogy being that the function that takes x to x+2, say, has type `Int -> Int` rather than `Int -> Int -> Int`). Will it work if instead I give `foo` the type `Type1 -> Type2` and then allow the definition of `foo x` to mention `library`? If not, is there some other way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

If the Library information is needed at runtime you need to represent it in your types. It's not a constant by definition, so you need to express it in your functions.

You can get easier levels of code reuse though by using the Reader monad to thread this dependency across the program.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now trying to get my head round the Reader monad, but it does indeed look like what I'm after.